# how to increase video volume in android emulator?

Tags: android, volume, voice

When I run video on my android emulator, it's volume is slow.

So anybody have ans for that. So please give me hint.

Thanks in advance,
Prashant

Answer (score -1):

Run it on a real device to find out if the problem is in fact a problem or not. Running such things on the slow emulator won't give you a the performance of a real device.